# Small Application Taking Time To Load

Tags: web-applications, jsf, icefaces

I have a small web application developed using Icefaces 1.8.2 and jsf 1.1 which is deployed to Oracle Application Server 10.1.3. I have noticed that it is taking a while to load the application initially and once loaded speed is satisfactory.

How can I improve the initial loading time of the application?

Update 1

I a query which takes 2-3 seconds in back end, however when I render  the same in front-end it takes almost 7 seconds. Number of rows is only 1080. I am rendering these records in datatable. What could be the reason for this?

Update 2

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_3.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.debugDOMUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
        <description>State saving method: "client" or "server" (= default) See JSF Specification
                     2.5.2</description>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.concurrentDOMViews</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.connectionTimeout</param-name>
        <param-value>100000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.standardRequestScope</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.redirectTracker.POLICY</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.custom.redirectTracker.policy.FullRedirectTrackPolicy</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>app1</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Faces Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- extension mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.iface</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/block/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10000</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!-- Welcome files -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.icesoft.faces.util.event.servlet.ContextEventRepeater</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.2.xsd">    
    <security:authentication-manager alias="_authenticationManager" />   
    <bean id="authenticationProvider"
          class="com.icesoft.icefaces.security.UserDetailsAuthenticationProvider">
        <security:custom-authentication-provider/>
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.icesoft.icefaces.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl">      
         <constructor-arg ref="userRepository"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="userRepository"
          class="com.icesoft.icefaces.security.UserDaoImpl"/>
    <bean id="ntlmFilter" class="org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmProcessingFilter">
        <security:custom-filter position="NTLM_FILTER"/>
        <property name="stripDomain" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultDomain" value="XYZ"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="_authenticationManager" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ntlmEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.ui.ntlm.NtlmProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
        <property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/accessDenied.jspx"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="ntlmEntryPoint"/>
    </bean>
    <security:http access-denied-page="/denied.xhtml" entry-point-ref="ntlmEntryPoint"
                   servlet-api-provision="false">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied.jspx" filters="none"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: What browsers did you test? MSIE has serious HTML table rendering issues.

Comment: I tested in MSIE and Firefox, both browsers almost taking 7 seconds to load the page.

Comment: OK, that excludes the client. Left behind the bandwidth (apart from the odd requirement to show 1K rows at once in a single page, who is ever going to view them all?). Has the container GZIP compression turned on?

Comment: @BalusC I am not aware of GZIP compresssion, that is something which we need to turn it on in apps sever?

Comment: Yes. It can save the bandwidth up to 70% and every self respected webbrowser supports it. In Tomcat for example, it's a matter of setting `compression="on"` in the `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml`. Give it a try.

Comment: By the way, it's still beyond me why you would ever present 1K rows to the enduser in a single page. Just provide a search form so that the enduser doesn't need to use the browser's builtin Ctrl+F functionality. Just provide pagination so that the enduser doesn't need get RSI by endlessly driving the scrollwheel. And the last but not least, your page loads *way* faster. Look how Google does it :)

Comment: Any ideas where  I could turn it on in Oracle Apps Server?

Comment: No idea. I've never touched it. Just ask your serveradmin. Or if you're supposed to be the one (...) read the documentation.

Comment: @BalusC Apparently Oracle AS container doesn't support gzip compression.

Comment: Then homegrow a `Filter` which does that. You can find several examples in the web.

Comment: As I understands from our Apps DBA that even adding tailor made `Filter` is not an option. GZIP compression could be achieved with installation of Oracle Web Cache on top of Oracle AS container. This seems a rather dim idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use pagination at database-end rather then fetching all records at a time. The end-user will see at-most 10-20 records at a time on screen & probably will neglect most of the results.

Also you can introduce sorting on specific columns so that the user can find results better. Let user migrate to the specific result page directly of the total result pages found, without going through each result page.

This will reduce fetching unnecessary records from the database & may increase performance when accessed by many users.

Comment: @Nayan, I have only 1080 records, so do you think this could be anything to do with load on database or number of records are high? I seriously doubt. Most importantly this application is in testing phase and currently there is only a single user is accessing the application.

Comment: As suggested in another post, I don't see any reason to go for application server & you also mentioned it is a small application. From the details provided i.e data & server, I can say try using web-server. Also retrieve data from database, but keep it differed from view - don't display it on page, so it can be found whether data retrieval is slow or displaying it on page takes time.

Comment: If the DB and the appserver are on the same network, getting all records from the DB at once doesn't slow things down. When using datatable pagination, only the records on that "page" are transfered from the appserver to the client's browser. Transfer time between the appserver and the DB is negligible. However, if both are on a different network or have a slower link in between, then you can use database pagination

Comment: @Ali Its a good practice to implement pagination whether its a performance hit or not. In future, there might be server migration & then changing the things isn't favorable.

Comment: I have managed to reduce the time taking to fetch records. Now the only remains is time taking to load the application. Not sure how to improve the speed of loading small application.

Comment: @Polappan Are you caching data on application startup or doing some processing, then try delaying it. If this isn't the case, then its the application server taking time to load application.

Comment: @Nayan Wadekar I am not caching data during start up. Infact I am using Spring NTLM for windows authentication. I have added my web.xml, applicationContext.xml as update 3. Do you find anything suspicious or any wrong entries?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing on a different application server?  I've not used Oracle Application Server, but I have seen significantly slower start up for an app running on jetty compared to the same app running on Tomcat.
I suggest trying Tomcat.  Even if that's not an actual deployment option for you, this should at least help diagnosis.

Comment: Does change in apps server makes any difference?

Comment: You might be interested in this [comparison of app servers](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/blog/java-ee-container-heaven-hell-survey-results/) which is referenced from another [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455397/comparison-of-application-server-startup-times).  My test was using Tomcat 7 though, whereas this survey only covers up to Tomcat 6.  However, it clearly shows that both Tomcat and Jetty have faster redeploy and app start times than Oracle app server.

Comment: I appreciate with what you have mentioned. However we do not have any other option than Oracle Apps Sever. Manager would not agree for a change in container.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the performance of the application to a satisfactory level by re-writing some code and sql statements.

Thanks to all for the help.